# Is it possible make Watson Assistant search a data on IBM Cloudant?

Tags: ibm-watson, cloudant, watson-assistant

I am developing a chat bot using IBM Watson Assistant. Because the project is still in its early stage, I am still using the free plan. Everything was working relatively well until a couple weeks ago when I hit a brick wall.

I need my Assistant to communicate with IBM's database Cloudant but it just won't work. I set up the webhook as instructed, and gave full adm permission to my Assistant, but, every time I try to make it call the database, an error occurs. The error code is 405, which is supposed to be an error related to language, but both my data base and my assistant were created with the same language (this case, it is Portuguese-Brazil).

Unfortunately, Watson has no detailed log to analyse, so error code 405 is all I got.

I am looking for answers ever since, but haven't found anything yet.

So, I have to ask: is it possible to make Watson Assistant connect with Cloudant?

### Edit

I am adding screenshots:

1) [This is Cloudant's overview page. Here, I copied the external endpoint.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T20e8.png)

2) [The, I opened my assistant, called "Teste_BD", and pasted the endpoint in the URL field in order to set it up as a webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp43J.png)

3) [In this screen, I gave full adm permissions to my Test_BD Assistant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKJFM.png)

4) [Here is where I created a node to test. The idea is as simple as it gets: it will enter by recognizing the "Test" intent as soon as I type "hi". It is supposed to search for any of the keys set and save on the "$result" variable...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbvAG.png)

5) [... then, it is supposed to print the result on a sentence. In this case, it is meant to print the "id" number if it is found or print anything else the variable might have store in the "anything_else" condition.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Vu9.png)

6) [And that's when the error is triggered. As I said there is no log to consult, despite the error message clearly saying so...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AP8A.png)

7) [... the best I could get, is this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPf0F.png)

8) [Also, as you can see, the system just associate the value "null" for the variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7rJu.png)

9) At first, I thought the Assistant was just not recognizing the webhook, so I altered it to some nonsense just to see what would happen.

10) It triggered another error message saying the URL was not valid, so, at least, I got the confirmation that my Assistant was recognizing the Cloudant URL as valid.

Comment: What have you tried. Show us the code. '405' sounds like a HTTP error code (Method not allowed). Maybe you are calling the endpoint incorrectly.

Comment: This one connects with Db2, a relational database: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html#build-a-database-driven-slackbot

Answer (score 2):

You would use webhooks for something like this. If you can share the full error message coming back from the cloudant API that might help. Also any screenshots of how your webhook is set up could be helpful as well.